# Writing a macro that writes a macro to another Excel-file

Tags: vba

I have some VBA code that I need to copy to a lot of worksheets (it's Event-handling, so it's located in the sheets rather than a module).

Question: Is it possible to write a macro that allows me to select all the workbooks I need to modify, then automatically write the code to every sheet of all of the selected workbooks?

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to copy a module from one project to another. To accomplish this task, you must export the module from the Source VBProject and then import that file into the Destination VBProject. The code below will do this.

The function declaration is:

```
Function CopyModule(ModuleName As String, _
                    FromVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject, _
                    ToVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject, _
                    OverwriteExisting As Boolean) As Boolean
```

`ModuleName` is the name of the module you want to copy from one project to another.

`FromVBProject` is the `VBProject` that contains the module to be copied. This is the source `VBProject`.

`ToVBProject` is the `VBProject` in to which the module is to be copied. This is the destination `VBProject`.

`OverwriteExisting` indicates what to do if `ModuleName` already exists in the `ToVBProject`. If this is `True` the existing `VBComponent` will be removed from the `ToVBProject`. If this is `False` and the `VBComponent` already exists, the function does nothing and returns `False`.

The function returns `True` if successful or `False` if an error occurs. The function will return `False` if any of the following are true:

```
FromVBProject is nothing.
ToVBProject is nothing.
ModuleName is blank.
FromVBProject is locked.
ToVBProject is locked.
ModuleName does not exist in FromVBProject.
ModuleName exists in ToVBProject and OverwriteExisting is False.
```

The complete code is shown below:

```
Function CopyModule(ModuleName As String, _
    FromVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject, _
    ToVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject, _
    OverwriteExisting As Boolean) As Boolean
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' CopyModule
    ' This function copies a module from one VBProject to
    ' another. It returns True if successful or  False
    ' if an error occurs.
    '
    ' Parameters:
    ' --------------------------------
    ' FromVBProject         The VBProject that contains the module
    '                       to be copied.
    '
    ' ToVBProject           The VBProject into which the module is
    '                       to be copied.
    '
    ' ModuleName            The name of the module to copy.
    '
    ' OverwriteExisting     If True, the VBComponent named ModuleName
    '                       in ToVBProject will be removed before
    '                       importing the module. If False and
    '                       a VBComponent named ModuleName exists
    '                       in ToVBProject, the code will return
    '                       False.
    '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim FName As String
    Dim CompName As String
    Dim S As String
    Dim SlashPos As Long
    Dim ExtPos As Long
    Dim TempVBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Do some housekeeping validation.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If FromVBProject Is Nothing Then
        CopyModule = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Trim(ModuleName) = vbNullString Then
        CopyModule = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If ToVBProject Is Nothing Then
        CopyModule = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If FromVBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_locked Then
        CopyModule = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If ToVBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_locked Then
        CopyModule = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set VBComp = FromVBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        CopyModule = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' FName is the name of the temporary file to be
    ' used in the Export/Import code.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    FName = Environ("Temp") & "\" & ModuleName & ".bas"
    If OverwriteExisting = True Then
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' If OverwriteExisting is True, Kill
        ' the existing temp file and remove
        ' the existing VBComponent from the
        ' ToVBProject.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        If Dir(FName, vbNormal + vbHidden + vbSystem) <> vbNullString Then
            Err.Clear
            Kill FName
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                CopyModule = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        With ToVBProject.VBComponents
            .Remove .Item(ModuleName)
        End With
    Else
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' OverwriteExisting is False. If there is
        ' already a VBComponent named ModuleName,
        ' exit with a return code of False.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Err.Clear
        Set VBComp = ToVBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            If Err.Number = 9 Then
                ' module doesn't exist. ignore error.
            Else
                ' other error. get out with return value of False
                CopyModule = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Do the Export and Import operation using FName
    ' and then Kill FName.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    FromVBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName).Export Filename:=FName

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Extract the module name from the
    ' export file name.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    SlashPos = InStrRev(FName, "\")
    ExtPos = InStrRev(FName, ".")
    CompName = Mid(FName, SlashPos + 1, ExtPos - SlashPos - 1)

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Document modules (SheetX and ThisWorkbook)
    ' cannot be removed. So, if we are working with
    ' a document object, delete all code in that
    ' component and add the lines of FName
    ' back in to the module.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set VBComp = Nothing
    Set VBComp = ToVBProject.VBComponents(CompName)

    If VBComp Is Nothing Then
        ToVBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:=FName
    Else
        If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
            ' VBComp is destination module
            Set TempVBComp = ToVBProject.VBComponents.Import(FName)
            ' TempVBComp is source module
            With VBComp.CodeModule
                .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
                S = TempVBComp.CodeModule.Lines(1, TempVBComp.CodeModule.CountOfLines)
                .InsertLines 1, S
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            ToVBProject.VBComponents.Remove TempVBComp
        End If
    End If
    Kill FName
    CopyModule = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to look into the VBComponents to accomplish this kind of tasks

You first need to activate the reference called "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility"

Try the following code:

```
Sub Test_InsertCode()

    Dim Commands As String
    Commands = Chr(13) & _
                "Private Sub TestNewCode()" & Chr(13) & _
                "    MsgBox ""You Win !!""" & Chr(13) & _
                "End Sub"

    Dim VBComps As VBComponents
    Set VBComps = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents

    Dim VBComp As VBComponent
    Dim VBCodeMod As CodeModule

    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    For Each oSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set VBComp = VBComps(oSheet.CodeName)
        Set VBCodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
        InsertCode VBCodeMod, Commands
    Next oSheet

    'Here's a quick example of how to insert code in a new Module
    Set VBComp = VBComps.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    InsertCode VBComp.CodeModule, Commands

End Sub

Private Function InsertCode(VBCodeMod As CodeModule, Commands As String)

    Dim LineNum As Long
    With VBCodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, Commands
    End With

End Function
```

nb. when you run it in break mode, ( or line by line ? ) it generates a bug right after the code is copied. You need to run it all at once..

This code is working for Excel 2003, there might be some security issues that I'm not aware of when running it on later versions.

Comment: If you change "ThisWorkbook" to "ActiveWorkbook", you can add the code to any open workbook.

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve the worksheet, on-event part, but this is a simple solution for moving modules from one workbook to another.

Note - You do need the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility" references turned on as noted one above.

In short, the code will work (without all the housekeeping validations). Obviously you can get much fancier and error proof/handling, but this is the basics. The function exports the module to a file directory from your FromVBProject, then imports to your ToVBProject.

```
Function CopyModule (ModuleName as String, FromVBProject as VBIDE.VBProject, _  
                     ToVBProject as VBIDE.VBProject, _ 
                     FileLocation as String) as Boolean
Dim fileDirectory as String

fileDirectory = filelocation & ModuleName & ".bas"
FromVBProject.VBComponents.Item(ModuleName).Export fileDirectory
ToVBProject.Import fileDirectory

Kill fileDirectory

CopyModule = True

End Function

Sub CopyModuleToOtherWorkbook()

Dim destinationWorkbook as Workbook
Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks("destiationWorkbook.xlsm")

CopyModule "TestModule", ThisWorkbook.VBProject, destinationWorkbook.VBProject, "C:\my documents\macros\"   

'Assuming you want to save the workbook you just copied the module to
 destinationWorkbook.SaveAs C:\my documents\macros\ & desintationWorkbook.Name, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

 End sub
```

Comment: Because answer order can and does shift, I recommend removing the references to the other answers and simply explaining directly why that sort of attempt doesn't work. Explanation of the functioning of your answer would also be helpful.