# How can I get a macro to automatically carry forward from my template workbook to a newly created workbook regardless of the new filename?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is the main template for our group.  Within this template I have several tabs that I would like to incorporate macros on for hiding and unhiding of rows based on values.  I setup this macro on one tab, tested it out and it worked.  However, when I went through the process of what the users will be doing the macro did not carry forward to the new workbook.  I do not want to waste time doing the macro on the other sheets if I am unable to have the macro carry forward.  Can someone please help as my template is due today?

In case more info is needed on the process of the template....The template opens up with a User form for the individual to enter in specific information and then during the process of the uploading of an information feed it creates a new workbook.

Comment: what is your template/file extension? '.xlsx'?, '.xlsm', '.xltx', '.xltm' or any other?

Comment: *.xls is the file extension.

Comment: show the code which creates new workbook. or just answer- does it create new one or the old one  is save as new one?? here is the point...

Comment: It creates a new one.

Comment: if your code is within `Sheet module` of template file you need to copy the sheet to new workbook and your code will be copied, too. If your code is within any standard type of `Module` then you would need to use very sophisticated coding (which is not recommended) to copy code to new workbook.

Comment: If i find out that different that it saves as a new one is the answer any different?

Comment: if your template is `saveAs` than each time all your template macros will be also in new Workbook.

Comment: If you have enabled programmatic access to VBAProject you could programmatically "write" the macro into the new workbook. Or copy an existing module from the template to the new workbook.

Comment: How can you programmtically "write" the macro into the new workbook?  I don't want to be updating 40 different workbooks with this macro.

Comment: I am new to macros which is why I asked in my previous question about how to programmatically "write" a macro into the template to carry forward the individual tab macro.

Comment: the answer from @retailcoder is this 'very sophisticated coding' which I've mentioned earlier... If you are beginner in VBA I would rather suggest you not to go this direction.

Comment: Thanks for the responses but I still would like to know not only for my benefit what the "sophisticated coding" would be but also save time for my programmers since it looks like I have to pass this on to them since I only have VB and not the VBAProject program on my pc.

Comment: you need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710555/writing-a-macro-that-writes-a-macro-to-another-excel-file/12712022#12712022). And full references are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278951)

Comment: Posted the "very sophisticated" code in question. Actually it's using the "sophisticated" object model, but in a way that makes it as easy as coding it manually into each workbook you generate... except you only code it once. And you're not inserting code strings into dynamically instanciated virtual fancy code modules, you're just importing existing modules into the VBProject. Simple as 1-2-3, and much, much easier to debug when that becomes a need :)

Answer (score 1):

Write your template macro in a code module, then save and right-click the .bas module in the solution explorer, and export the module to a location you'll programmatically load it from later.

Then in another module, write the procedure that creates the workbook. Before saving the new workbook, load the exported module file into the workbook's `VBProject.VBComponents` collection, like this:

```
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
'...set up target workbook
targetWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "module1.bas"
targetWorkbook.SaveAs "workbook.xls"
```

**EDIT**

If your macro code needs to listen to Excel's events (and/or worksheet events), you'll need to also add a **class module** where you're going to do exactly that. A **code module** will need to instantiate it for the class module's code to run. 
Create a new class module and call it something like "clsExcelApp":

```
Private WithEvents xlApp As Excel.Application
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set xlApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then you can write event handlers for `xlApp`, such as:

```
Private Sub xlApp_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    'do something whenever a worksheet gets activated.
End Sub

Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    'do something before a workbook gets saved.
End Sub
```

The code module would only need to instantiate it, like this:

```
private App As New clsExcelApp
Option Explicit
```

The rest of the module could be macros and/or functions:

```
Public Sub Macro1()
    'do something
End Sub

Public Function Smurf(Range As Excel.Range) As Long
    'Smurf the Range and then smurf a Long
End Function
```

Then save your hard work and export all modules and import them programmatically into the workbook you want to "inject" the functionality into.

> **Note** You should always restrict access to `VBProject`, but to execute the `Excel.Workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(String)`
>   method you'll need it enabled. Just remember to turn the security back
>   on when you're done - better safe than sorry!

Comment: For Excel 2007+ you would need to `SaveAs` a *macro-enabled workbook*, (.xlsm).