# transferring variable form one workbook to another workbook vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a userform (userform1) in workbookA and in the userform, I'll be needing a module(module1) created in other workbook (workbookB) to made some calculation. In order to launch the calculation, the module need some info (TTAA, tolerance). I would really love to know the easiest way to transfer some variable from userform1(workbookA.userform1) to module1(workbookB.module1) and re-transfer the results to userform1.

below, you can find a small part of the programm which I've coded to call the module.

```
TTAA = CDbl(Me.TTAA_textbox.Value)
tolerance = CDbl(Me.tolerance_textbox.Value)
application.Run ("'Workbooks.xls'!module1")
```

I've declared as public, the variable `TTAA` and `tolerance` in the module1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (which I know to work) is to temporarily "save" the variable on a sheet in one of either file and then reference it as

```
Worksheets.Add.Name = "tmp"
Workbooks(WorkbookA.Name).Worksheets("tmp").Range("A1").Value2
'And remove it later on
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(WorkbookA.Name).Worksheets("tmp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

An alternative might be to declare the `subs` in WorkbookB as functions. Apart from `public` variables this is the only way to get return values (in a native format) from independent VBA code segments. Yet, if you had no luck with `public` variables I doubt this will work.

But why don't you import the module into WorkbookA instead? The following SO answer might be able to help you with that.
[Writing a macro that writes a macro to another Excel-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710555/writing-a-macro-that-writes-a-macro-to-another-excel-file)