# What is the easiest way to add Macro automatically to a set of Excel Files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro function that I have added to an excel file. My question is how can I add the same macro function to a specific set of excel files without copy pasting the macro in each excel vba editor.What is the easiest way to achieve this?

The objective is for the users who have no knowledge on excel macros should be able to easily add Macros to excel and execute it.

Comment: Like [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710555/writing-a-macro-that-writes-a-macro-to-another-excel-file)? (just loop through all excel files in a directory or whatever you need)

Comment: Questions asking for the "easiest" way of doing something are never good questions as they are biased based on taste / skills. These questions tend to lead to discussions and this website is not meant for discussions. This website is meant for clear questions and answers only. No chit chat: http://stackoverflow.com/tour Anyway, the means to achieve what you are looking for are - as far as I know - (1) add an Add-In to Excel (2) write a macro to alter Excel files and insert macros into these files (3) write a macro to import the data from the files without macros into the file with macros.

Answer (score 1):

If the people who are importing the macros are also the users of these macros you might want to create an add-in out of your vba macro. The procedure is described [here](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm). The users would just have to install the add-in on their PCs once([step 4](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm)). They can then use the add-in for several Excel-files.

This needs to be done by each user once:

> Step 4: Install the Add-In:
>
> Go to Tools > Add-Ins to open the Add-Ins dialog. If you have stored your Add-In in the default location you will see its name displayed in the Add-Ins available: window (if you have stored your Add-In in a different folder, use the [Browse] button to find it). Click on your Add-In's name to see its description at the bottom of the dialog box.
>
> To install your Add-In place a tick in the check-box next to your Add-In's name and click [OK]. [Click the thumbnail below to see a full-sized image]...
>
> Installing your Add-In (Excel 2002)     Installing your Add-In (Excel 2000/97)
>
> As soon as the Add-In is installed its functions will be available in Excel. Find them in the User Defined section of the Function Wizard (Paste Function Tool) or simply type them into a cell as you would any built-in function. The Add-In will remain installed until you return to the Add-Ins dialog and uninstall it by removing the tick from the check-box.