# Add VBA Code to an Excel Sheet with Openpyxl?

Tags: excel, vba, openpyxl

I like to automatically generate Excel workbooks with openpyxl. I have a master macros workbook, and Excel will let me run macros that I wrote in the master workbook on another open auto-generated workbook. Now, I would like to run a macro with a clickable cell, which I can accomplish. The only issue I have, is that code must be written in the specific sheet that the macro will run in.

Code in the "Modules" folder can be run if the module is in another workbook. But the "Microsoft Excel Objects" are specific to each sheet.

Is it possible to use openpyxl to edit the code in "Sheet1" under "Microsoft Excel Objects"?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? [Writing a macro that writes a macro to another Excel-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710555/writing-a-macro-that-writes-a-macro-to-another-excel-file)

Comment: I think [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html) can do it, though I've never tried. I've never seen anything in openpyxl that can. You could create a template that has the sheet code that then calls the module code and always use the template when creating the new files.